# facebook graph api post picture

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm having problem with getting picture from the facebook post via Graph API. It used to work but something has changed and I'm getting "(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher"

Does anyone had similar problem and know how to workaround it ?

Reproduction steps:

Request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10155765892248481/picture?type=album
```

Response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 12,
      "fbtrace_id": "BBWPqs8AYts"
   }
}
```

Comment: I also did request with userID_postID -> https://graph.facebook.com/63889783480_10155765892248481/picture?type=album  and still the same error

Comment: Getting a different error when trying that request with a user post - “(#12) picture edge for this type is deprecated for versions v2.3 and higher” Works fine when I ask for it as a field though, `id?fields=picture`

Comment: @misorude can you please paste what did you do to get the post picture ? thank you

Comment: Can’t do it for the post id you have given (no access), but basically just what I said: Asked for the `picture` _field_, `post_id?fields=picture`